# Как сделать скрывающееся меню при скролле вверх?

Tags: jquery, вёрстка, menu, fixed

Есть горизонтальное фиксированное меню в самом верху страницы. Изначально оно невидимо, написал скрипт на JQuery чтобы при прокрутке в 300px экрана оно показывалось (скрипт работает).Можно ли как то дописать этот скрипт, чтобы при прокрутке обратно (снизу страницы до самого верха) меню меняло свою прозрачность скажем на 0.3 (т.е чтобы становилось прозрачным, но видимым) и соответственно когда снова будем прокручивать вниз на 300px, прозрачность снова становилась = 1. У меня только получается полностью его скрыть при прокрутке вверх, как изменить только прозрачность, не знаю.

Comment: Если Вы покажете Ваш код, можно будет предложить варианты. Самое простое - это менять при скролле opacity: $('.menu').css('opacity','0.3')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На JQ не умею, вот просто чистый JS

```js
var header = document.querySelector('#header')



document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= 300) {
    header.classList.add('opa')

  } else {
    header.classList.remove('opa')

  }
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 150%;
  width: 100%;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #039be5;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

#header.opa {
  opacity: .31;
}
```

```html
<header id="header"></header>
```